# How to sum object by time period on a Map object by stream in Java8?

Tags: java

I have a Map object. The `key` is ID, value is a list of `Transaction`. Below is the Transaction class code:

```
public class Transaction {
    private double amount;
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
...
}

Map transactions = new HashMap<String, List<Transaction>>();

// how to stream transactions here?
```

I am trying to get the sum amount of transactions happen within 24 hours for each `key`. First, I need to loop transaction List for each key. Then group by the transaction based on timestamp. Then sum the value for each grouped transaction.

For example, the map object has below value:

```
'012345': [ {'05-05-2019:10.00.00', 100}, {'05-05-2019:11.00.00', 100},{'05-05-2019:12.00.00', 100} ]
`678900`: [ {'05-06-2019:10.00.00', 100}, {'05-06-2019:11.00.00', 100},{'05-07-2019:10.30.00', 100} ]
```

It has two keys `012345` and `678900`, and each key has three transactions. The transactions under the key `012345` happens within 24 hours while the transactions under `678900` happens across 2 days. The output should be the sum of amount for 24 hours window period. So it looks like:

```
'012345': [300],
'678900': [200, 200]
```

The three transactions under `678900` has two 24 hours window period. So it gives two 200 amount. The middle transaction get calculated twice since it is covered by two 24 hours window period.

Below is my thinking:

```
transactions.values().forEach(txnList -> {
            Map<Integer, DoubleSummaryStatistics> collect = txnList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(txn -> txn.getTimestamp().getHour() / 24, Collectors.summarizingDouble(Transaction::getAmount)));
        });
```

but it doesn't return the right value. I don't know how I should proceed this logic. Can anyone point me the right way to do that?

Comment: I don't quite get the grouping logic. Can you provide sample input and output?

Comment: I have updated the question and give an example on that. Please let me know whether it makes sense?

Comment: Much clearer. But I doubt streams will help you here.

Comment: Should transaction older than 24h be skipped?

Comment: @SergeyBzhezitskiy not skip any transaction. But need to calculate the sum based on 24h window

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is exactly the **wrong class** to be using here. That class **cannot represent a moment** as it lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. For a transaction timestamp, use the `java.time.Instant` class to represent a moment in UTC with a resolution as fine as nanoseconds. `Instant.now()`. Seach Stack Overflow, this has been covered many many  times already.

Comment: Tip: For exchanging date-time values as text, use only standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. Example: `2019-05-24T03:54:44Z`

Comment: @BasilBourque yes, sure. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to use a third party library, there are some APIs available in [Eclipse-Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/), which will do your job pretty neatly. This works with any Java `java.lang.Iterable`. The code would look like follows:

```
    Map<String, List<Transaction>> transactionsMap = getMapOfTransactionalData(...);
    final long currentTime = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
    Map<String, Double> idTransactionSumMap = MapIterate.collect(transactionsMap, (id, transList) -> {
        Collection<Transaction> transactionsForTimeRange = Iterate.select(transList, transaction -> {
            // Implement your condition to compare time, below is just an example, you can define your range as well
            long transactionTime = transaction.getTimestamp().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
            return transactionTime > currentTime - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(24);
        });
        return Tuples.pair(id, Iterate.sumOfDouble(transactionsForTimeRange, Transaction::getAmount));
    });
```

If you use MutableMap and MutableList from eclipse-collection, code will be like:

```
MutableMap<String, MutableList<Transaction>> transactionsMap = getMapOfTransactionalData(...);
long currentTime = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
MutableMap<String, Double> idTransactionSumMap = transactionsMap.collect((id, transList) -> Tuples.pair(id, transList.select(transaction -> {
    // your condition to compare time
    long transactionTime = transaction.getTimestamp().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    return transactionTime > currentTime - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(24);
}).sumOfDouble(Transaction::getAmount)));
```

Comment: Thanks for this post. Can't native steam support this feature?

Comment: what is `currentTime`? I don't really need currentTime. I need to compare among transaction time.

Comment: This should work:`Map<String, List<Double>> idToTransactionsDayWiseMap = transactionsMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, transactionList -> transactionList.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(transaction -> transaction.getTimestamp().getYear() + transaction.getTimestamp().getMonth().toString() + transaction.getTimestamp().getDayOfMonth())).values().stream().map(transactions -> transactions.stream().mapToDouble(Transaction::getAmount).sum()).collect(Collectors.toList())));`